# How to show the hermitian adjoint of two operator's kronecker product is equal to their hermitian adjoints' kronecker product?

Tags: operator-theory, adjoint-operators, kronecker-product

I mean, the question is simple, asking me to show $(A\otimes B)^* = A^*\otimes B^*$, where * is just the hermitian adjoints. However, it's hard for me to use the definition, aka put them into (x,y) just like the $+$ case, in fact, I am not even sure about the dimension since the kronecker product will be $n^2$ if the original matrices are square with dim $n$.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A \otimes B)^*$ is the unique linear operator satisfying
$$
\langle (A \otimes B)^* y, x\rangle = \langle y , (A\otimes B) x\rangle,
$$
for all $x, y \in H\otimes K$.

Now take any two product vectors in $v_1 \otimes w_1, v_2 \otimes w_2 \in H \otimes K$. Then for a product vector we find that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\langle v_1 \otimes w_1, (A\otimes B)(v_2\otimes w_2)\rangle &= \langle v_1 \otimes w_1, (Av_2) \otimes (Bw_2)\rangle \\
&= \langle v_1, A v_2\rangle \langle w_1, B w_2\rangle \\
&= \langle A^* v_1,v_2\rangle \langle B^* w_1,w_2\rangle \\
&= \langle (A^* \otimes B^*)(v_1 \otimes w_1), v_2 \otimes w_2\rangle.
\end{aligned}
$$

So we see that for any product vector the correct identity holds. Then by linearity of the inner product and the fact that we can write any vector as a linear combination of product vectors, we can extend this to all vectors in $H \otimes K$.